# True/False logic error with Telerik control C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, telerik

I was performing a validation on one of my fields when a very unusual event occurred. I had a very simple if statement based off the messagebox dialog button. All it was required to do was change my checkbox from true to false. I spent many hours trying to debug this to see what was going on. Every time the breakpoint showed the checkbox was false but it never displayed it on the form. It also would not go past the return statement. I used breakpoint on the return statement and it and it said it was true. (See Below)

```
private void rChkBoxB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rChkBoxB.Checked == false) return;//showed .Checked = true

    if (Convert.ToInt32(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text) > 256)
    {
        DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("B does not support numbering over 256!", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            rChkBoxB.Checked = false; //showed .Checked = false
        }
    }
}
```

I finally tried setting the value to true instead of false to try it, and it worked. (See Below)

```
private void rChkBoxBizerba_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rChkBoxBizerba.Checked == true) return;

    if (Convert.ToInt32(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text) > 256)
    {
        DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("Bizerba does not support numbering over 256!", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            rChkBoxBizerba.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

What would cause such a strange logic error to happen?

Comment: With standard checkboxes this doesn't happen. Telerik problem? Notice that you don't need to add the if statement. You have only the OK button in your messagebox

Comment: I had another issue before this but you are correct, I do not need that.

Comment: @Steve what is the difference though?

Comment: I don't know Telerik suite for WinForms, but a quick check on their documentation suggest that you are using the wrong event handler. You should work with the ToggleStateChanging event as explained here http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/buttons-checkbox-handling-radcheckbox-states.html . Let me know if you are able to solve your problem with this hint

Comment: @Steve unfortunately I started with ToggleStateChanged and it was causing my messagebox to fire twice that is why I went with click event.

Comment: ToggleStateChanging is the event to use. You could set the property cancel to true to block the firing of ToggleStateChanged See the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use, [as per docs from Telerik site](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/buttons-checkbox-handling-radcheckbox-states.html) the ToggleStateChanging event.

```
private void rChkBoxBizerba_ToggleStateChanging(object sender, StateChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.NewValue == ToggleState.On) 
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text) > 256)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show(.......);
            args.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Well, not sure that this is the logic you require, but the important thing is to handle the event ToggleStateChanging and setting the property args.Cancel to True if your logic dictates that the checkbox should not be checked (On according to Telerik bias)

Comment: I really appreciate your help Steve but I think to avoid more complication I am going to just use a standard checkbox.